# Can you have the bot initiate a message?

Tags: wit.ai

I am new to wit.ai trying to wrap my head on how the story builder works. 
If I wanted to have the bot initiate a conversation instead of the user triggering the start flow by asking a question, is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not possible but we will working on it soon. In the meantime, you can simulate to send a user message like "#Init" to trigger the first Bot Answer when you init you conversation.

Comment: thanks for the useful tip @l5t but can you please point me on a reference that does exactly the "#init"? Thanks!